# Problema con join:

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join

Tengo tres tablas en mi base de datos, la primera se llama usuarios la cual tiene datos básicos de un usuario.

[image: Tabla de usuarios]

La segunda se llama rolesusuarios en la cual tengo guardados los roles de usuarios.

[image: Tabla de roles de usuario]

La tercer tabla se llama usuarios_rolesusuarios es donde guardo la relacion entre usuarios y sus roles. Todas tienen datos guardados.

[image: relacion de usuarios y roles de usuario]

Con esa consulta quise mostrar cuales son mis usuarios y que rol tienen. pero al ejecutarla no muestra nada.

```
SELECT u.id_usuario, u.nombre_usuario, ru.rolusuario 
FROM usuarios_rolesusuarios AS uru 
JOIN usuarios AS u ON uru.id_usuario = u.id_usuario
JOIN rolesusuarios AS ru 
ON uru.id_rolusuario = ru.id_rolusuario;
```

¿Alguien tiene idea de cual puede ser mi error?

Comment: Ve ejecutando en tu consulta primero con un join a la vez para ver si así identificamos por dónde está el fallo

Comment: El problema está en los valores de este `JOIN`: **`ON uru.id_rolusuario = ru.id_rolusuario`**  si observas bien, en una tabla tienes valores así: `caru1, caru2...` pero en la otra tienen un `0`, por lo tanto nunca coinciden: `caru01, caru02...`

Comment: Tienes que revisar también las relaciones con `id_usuario`, al menos en la captura se ven valores como `AICC8333042` y en la otra tabla valores similares, pero con caracteres adicioales al final `AICC8333042gf`. no sé si son pruebas y haya realmente valores coincidentes en otras filas. Debes revisar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, aun estoy en etapa de pruebas antes de lanzar oficialmente la base de datos a producción. Agraadezco las observaciones realizadas a esta pregunta. Buen día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en tu último `JOIN`:

```
... ON uru.id_rolusuario = ru.id_rolusuario;
```

Veamos los valores:

En la tabla `usuarios_rolesusuarios`, cuyo alias es `uru`, la columna **`id_rolusuario`**  tiene los valores así:

```
id_rolusuario
------------------
caru01
caru02
caru03
.... etc
```

En la tabla `roles_usuarios` cuyo alias es `ru`, la columna **`id_rolusuario`** tiene los datos así:

```
id_rolusuario
------------------
caru1
caru2
caru3
.... etc
```

Como podrás comprender, **`caru1` no es igual a `caru01`... etc, por lo tanto el `JOIN` nunca se cumple** porque en una de las tablas los valores tienen un `0` y en la otra no.

Por otra parte, debes revisar también las coincidencias con respecto a `id_usuario`, al menos en la captura de pantalla se ve un valor como `AICC8333042` y en otra tabla se ve un valor similar, pero con una `gf` al final. No sé si realmente hay ids coincidentes en otras filas o no ¿?

Comment: Muchas gracias, de verdad no se porque pase por alto ese detalle con los ID's.y de plano confundí algunos valores, pero gracias por señalarme las ocurrencias.

Comment: @FelipeLs me alegro, como dicen, muchos ojos ven más que dos. Considera marcar la respuesta si te ha ayudado a resolver el problema, para que la pregunta no aparezca como no respondida. Saludos.